# Fastest way to search nearest and furthest rectangle in 2D space

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Suppose now in the 2D space, we have a list of rectangles **a**, **b**, **c** as the following figure shows:

```
_______
|___a_|
         _______
         |     |
         |__b__|


  _______
  |___c_|
```

Now what I want to do is for each rectangle, I want to find the nearest rectangle and furthest rectangle. For example, for rectangle **a**, its nearest rectangle is **b** while its furthest rectangle is **c**. Of course, one brute force way of solving this problem is for each    rectangle, calculate its distance to the rest rectangles. I think there should be fast algorithm for this problem. For example, I can divide the 2D space into 10 by 10 squares, and then calculate the position of the rectangle in this space. When I calculate the nearest rectangle, I only search the rectangles in neighboring squares. Any other ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT**:
I admit that using [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) is a good solution if I only have interest in getting the nearest rectangle. But here, I also want to know the furthest rectangle. I am not sure using k-d tree will help in this case.

Comment: Build a quadtree containing the rectangles. The distances search is then easier.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks, and could you give more details?

Comment: Which details? Do you understand [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)?

Comment: Are distances measured from the centers or from the borders?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner it is calculated from the borders.

Comment: [Any of these should help](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning#Data_structures)

Comment: The fastest way for searching would be to have already precomputed the shortest and furthest rectangle for each rectangle

Comment: I am still not 100% sure about your distance measure. I assume, all your rects are aligned to the x,y axes. Let’s consider only 2 unit squares whose centers are at 0,0 and 3,0. The min distance, measured between the nearest borders, is then 1. The max distance, measured in the same way, is of course also 1. But the max distance measured between the furthest borders would be  5. Which one is right? I am asking since this influences the algorithm.

Comment: Do you mean the Euclidean distances ?

Comment: You should also admit that the grid only works for the closest rectangle, not for the furthest one.

Comment: [„Hierarchical Representations of Collections of Small Rectangles“](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~hjs/pubs/SameCSUR88.pdf) is a good tutorial survey by Hanan Samet. I suggest to lookup the section about R-Trees page 303 ff. My impression is that they could be used for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Such proximity problems are known to be solved by the Voronoi diagram for the closest and for the farthest neighbors.

These diagrams are known to be constructible in time O(n log(n)) for a set of points. For the farthest-polygon problem, an O(n log³(n)) solution is known. But I would not be surprised that for axis-aligned rectangle this bound can be lowered.

In any case, nothing trivial to implement.

Comment: Voronoi diagrams refer to distances to points, not to areas. I think, they cannot applied here, or do you have any idea, how?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: distances apply to sets in general, and so do Voronoi diagrams. I mentioned known solutions to the farthest-polygon problem. You are not obliged to believe me.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: you build the Voronoi diagrams which give you the nearest or farthest neighbors of every item.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: unfortunately, these algorithms are arduous.